# Six Operations: a natural transformation $i^! \to i^*$

Tags: sheaf-theory, derived-categories

Let $i : Z \to X$ be the inclusion of a closed subset of sufficiently nice spaces to support the six operations. I'm reading a paper where the author says there is a natural transformation of functors $i^! \to i^*$. Here $i^!$ is the exceptional inverse image and $i^*$ the inverse image being the usual functors $D^b(X) \to D^b(Z)$ of derived categories of (constructible) sheaves. For the life of me I am not able to figure out where this natural transformation is coming from. I know that in the six functor formalism we always have a natural transformation $i_! \to i_*$ which is an isomorphism in this case as the map $i$ is proper. I've tried playing around with the various adjunction maps, but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Consider the unit $id\to i_*i^*$ and apply $i^!$, you get $i^!\to i^!i_*i^*$. Now use that $i^!i_*=id$ and you get $i^!\to i^*$.

Comment: I don't see where the $i^! i_* = id$ coming from? Don't we only have the unit $id \to i^!i_*$?

Comment: You know that the counit $i^*i_*\to id$ is an isomorphism. So the right adjoints of $i^*i_*$ and of $id$ should also be isomorphic. The right adjoint of $id$ is of course $id$. The right adjoint of a composite is the composite in the reverse order of the right adjoints (if these exist), so the right adjoint of $i^*i_*$ is $i^!i_*$.  You can even show that the isomorphism $id=i^!i_*$ will be the one induced by the unit $id\to i^!i_*$.

Comment: Maybe a better way to see this : $i_*$ is fully faithful. It follows that the counit with its left adjoint $i^*i_*\to id$ and the unit with its right adjoint $id\to i^!i_*$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: Ahhh okay I see it now. Thanks!